# What is the difference between "check something for something" and "check something over for something"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between *check for* and *check over*? For example:

> I have to **check** my essay for mistakes.
>
> I have to **check** my essay **over** mistakes.

Does *over* imply greater carefulness in checking something? If so, then why people sometimes say just *check*? Don't they want something to be checked carefully?

Comment: I think you might be confusing "to check (something)" with the phrasal verb "to **look** (something) **over**." We don't really say "check over."

Comment: I have definitly heard "check over".

Comment: It does show up in some dictionaries, but it sounds funny to me, and checking Ngrams backs this up: "look over" is **far** more common. Just because you heard it doesn't make it right.

Comment: In school, I definitely would have frequently been told "make sure you check over your work (for mistakes)". Separating check over does make it sound awkward, though. It would never have been "make sure you check your work over".

Comment: If I check something *over*, it implies to me that I'm reading it through for at least a second time. In other words, I'm making an additional pass for a specific purpose. In short, I think of *over* as being synonymous with *again* in this context.

Comment: Incidentally, your second example sentence doesn't match your question—and it means something different. (You've omitted *for*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both mean the same thing, but *check over* specifically has connotations of proofreading and finding any errors, and also of checking the whole thing.

*Over* in this sense cannot replace *for*, though. It's still needed. If I were to say this phrase, I would not split *check* and *over* (in this context), as that sounds jarring.

I would suggest:

> I have to **check over** my essay.

With *for mistakes* being implied, as in this definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check%20over):

> Definition of check over : to look at (something or someone) in a
>   careful way to find problems, mistakes, etc.
>
> *checking* the new cars *over*
>
> The doctors *checked* him *over* for bruises.
>
> Be sure to *check over* each item on the list for any mistakes.